# How to logout the frameset in asp.net page

Tags: asp.net

I have a web page in that page I'm using 3 frame set one for heading, 2nd one for left side navigation and 3rd frame for main page. When i click left side navigation automatically main page will be displayed.

My problem is i have a Log out button in frame one(head page).when i click the logout button the frame one gets logout and displays the login page. frame 2nd and 3rd still exist i want to close all the frame and displays a complete login page in the browser.

I'm not using link button... 
I'm using Button(Asp.net)...

I need c# code only.....

can any one please help me......

Answer (score 4):

If your logout button is a link, simply set the target to "_top".

```
<a href="/myapp/logout" target="_top">Logout</a>
```

You can do the same if it's a button in a form (though that usage is deprecated).  If you are using a form, I'd suggest changing it to a link.

```
<form action="/myapp/logout" type="POST" target="_top">
    <button type="submit">Logout</button>
</form>
```

Comment: @Raj - using a LinkButton to connect to a handler on your form?  Try creating a Logout.aspx page and simply redirecting to that via a standard HTML link.

Comment: @tvanfosson im not using link button im using button in asp.net i need to place a code in onclick event(button).....

Comment: @tvanfosson bcoz i place a button for some 3d effect pupose.so i can't change to link button, when i click the button it automatically login page will displayed in the browser...

Comment: @Raj - my point is don't use a button, use a standard link.  If you want to handle it with javascript in a button handler you can do: `window.top.location = "/myapp/logout.aspx";`

Comment: @Raj - CSS would be a better way to handle the display issues.  See any of the "buttons" on this (StackOverflow) page.  They are a mixture of links and input buttons, but they share the same styling using CSS.

Comment: @Raj - by the time it gets to the server, it's too late.  You have to do this client side.  The best you can do on the server is to serve up a response that does one of the things I've mentioned on the client.